# How to make code using old version libs to pass building on playground?

Tags: anchor, spl-token

I got an example: https://beta.solpg.io/64e50b1a6f50baeacc2cd460

It failed to build on playground. I believe that this code tested on old version.

Also I found https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/43666698d467205ffa9ff8998edf42f62ce10780/tokens/transfer-tokens/anchor program not compiled on playground. Too many examples there online used old version dependent libs. How to migrate it to latest version? Is there migration guide available?

Or can we set libs version on playground?

It would be great if some guys can share examples link URL have create_token/mint_token/transfer_tokens instructions using latest version libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple, plain way to do it. Must to migrate API one by one.

We can checking ['playground supported crates'](https://github.com/solana-playground/solana-playground?tab=readme-ov-file#supported-crates)